# Bigquery filter two array columns

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a two columns that have been joined from two tables that i'm trying to filter like so:

```
row app1       app2
1   [app,app1] []
2   []         [app]
3   [app1]     [app]
4   []         []
```

now im trying to retrieve all rows where either app1 or app2 contain 'app'. I have come up with the following, however it will only return one row, which is row 3. The rows where either column is empty will not be returned.

```
    select * from table
    where exists(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(array(select app1 from table)) AS s, 
    UNNEST(array(select app2 from table)) AS d WHERE regexp_contains(format('%t',(s,d)), 
    'app'))
```

This only returns row 3, what I am expecting is rows 1,2,3 to be returned.

Any help with biqquery can be of great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... filter two array columns ... - ... retrieve all rows where either app1 or app2 contain 'app'

When `contain` references arrays rather then strings - I am assuming your are looking for array containing `app` as an element , not as a part of string!!
If my this is true - consider below

```
select *
from your_table
where 'app' in unnest(app1 || app2)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]